# Matching only first occurence of character in regex

Tags: java, regex

Hello I want to match all string like: `{ anything character }` , but I want to exclude double `{{ at first or }}` on the final of String. I tried to do this using a pattern like `^\\{.*\\}$` but this pattern match `{{ anything character }}` or  `{ anything character }}` and I don't want to match this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rule out a character or characters using a negated character class, for instance `[^{]` or `[^}]` or `[^{}]`. So one way would be:

```
/^\{[^{}]*\}$/
```

Live Example:

```js
const rex = /^\{[^{}]*\}$/;
console.log(rex.test("{matches}") ? "matches" : "doesn't match");
console.log(rex.test("{{doesn't match}}") ? "matches" : "doesn't match");
```

If you only wan to disallow `{` after the first `{` and `}` before the ending `}`, you can use negative lookahead for that:

```
/^\{(?!{).*\}(?!})$/
```

`(?!{)` means "No `{` here" but without consuming anything.

Live Example:

```js
const rex = /^\{(?!{).*\}(?!})$/;
console.log(rex.test("{matc{h}es}") ? "matches" : "doesn't match");
console.log(rex.test("{{doesn't match}}") ? "matches" : "doesn't match");
```